# Understanding code snippet open_clientfd(char *hostname, char *port) from book CSAPP?

Tags: c, sockets

As reading the book < Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective > and in the chapter of Network Programming, I saw a this function:

```
int open_clientfd(char *hostname, char *port) {
    int clientfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *listp, *p;

    /* Get a list of potential server addresses */
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;  /* Open a connection */
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV;  /* ... using a numeric port arg. */
    hints.ai_flags |= AI_ADDRCONFIG;  /* Recommended for connections */
    Getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &listp);

    /* Walk the list for one that we can successfully connect to */
    for (p = listp; p; p = p->ai_next) {

        /* Create the socket descriptor */
        if ((clientfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) < 0) 
            continue; /* Socket failed, try the next */
        if (connect(clientfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) != -1) 
            break; /* Success */
        Close(clientfd); /* Connect failed, try another */
    } 

    /* Clean up */
    Freeaddrinfo(listp);
    if (!p) /* All connects failed */
        return -1;
    else    /* The last connect succeeded */
        return clientfd;
}
```

what I don't understand is here this line `Close(clientfd); /* Connect failed, try another */`, because if the socket create failed, it will continue, if it successed, it will just break out of the for loop, seems this line will never get a chance to execute?

Comment: I think this code is reached if the socket creation succeeds (doesn't `continue`), but the `connect` fails (doesn't  `break`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `socket` was successful you have opened a socket. If `connect` fails, the socket still exists and has to be closed. The next cycle of the loop will use the next address from the list which may need different parameters for the `socket` call. That's why the existing socket is not re-used.